# Deadlock when throwing an exception in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, fork, deadlock

I'm investigating a report of a deadlock that occurred within my library, which is generally mutli-threaded and written in C++11. The stacktrace during the deadlock looks like this:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007fb4049e250d in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 1    Thread 0x7fb40533b740 (LWP 26259) "i-foca" 0x00007fb4049e250d in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007fb4049e250d in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fb40533b740 (LWP 26259)):
#0  0x00007fb4049e250d in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fb4049dde76 in _L_lock_941 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007fb4049ddd6f in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fb40403a0af in dl_iterate_phdr () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007fb3eb7f3bbf in _Unwind_Find_FDE () from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
#5  0x00007fb3eb7f0d2c in ?? () from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
#6  0x00007fb3eb7f16ed in ?? () from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
#7  0x00007fb3eb7f1b7e in _Unwind_RaiseException () from /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
#8  0x00007fb3eba56986 in __cxa_throw () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00007fb3e7b3dd39 in <my library>
```

The code that causes the deadlock is basically `throw NameError(...);`, which is to say, a standard C++ construct which is supposed to be thread-safe. However, the code deadlocks nevertheless, trying to acquire a mutex in GLIBC's `dl_iterate_phdr()`. The following additional information is known about the environment:

- Even though my library can spawn multiple threads, during the incident it ran in single-threaded mode, as evidenced by the stacktrace;
- The program where my library is used does extensive forking-without-exec;
- My library uses an at-fork handler in order to sanitize all its mutexes/threads when a fork occurs (however, I have no control over the mutexes in standard libraries). In particular, a fork cannot occur while an exception is being thrown.

I still don't understand how this deadlock could have occurred.

I'm considering the following scenarios, but not sure which one is possible and which one is not:

1. There are multiple child processes. One of them tries to throw an exception and crashes. If somehow the mutex that GLIBC uses is shared between child processes, and one of the children locks it but then fails to unlock because of the crash. Is it possible for a mutex to be shared in such a way?
2. Another library that I'm not aware of also uses multiple threads, and the fork happens when that library throws an exception in its code, which leaves the exception mutex in locked state in the child process. My library is then merely unfortunate enough to walk into this trap.
3. Any other scenario?

Comment: *I still don't understand how this deadlock could have occurred.* -- Given this, it will be almost impossible to diagnose an MT threading issue without actually running the program and seeing the error.

Comment: Btw is `-pthread` used when program linked?

Comment: @Slava We use only `-shared -m64 -g -lstdc++` when linking; do you believe `-pthread` would make a difference for a library that works just fine most of the time?

Comment: @Pasha you're linking in the C++ standard library explicitly... by any chance are you using a C compiler instead of a C++ compiler?

Comment: @StephenM.Webb I'm using `gcc version 8.3.1 20190311`; all source files have `.cc` extension, so I believe C++ language is chosen automatically. It won't be able to compile otherwise, I use C++ features extensively.

Comment: I've seen weird behaviour when program was comiled and linked without -pthread flag, so it should not take long to try

Comment: There's more to linking in the C++ runtime than just adding the standard library.  If you insist on linking your C++ as C, you might consider adding -fexceptions in to make sure other thread-related runtime glue is picked up correctly.  @Slava is right about -pthread as well: it doesn't just add libpthread.so to the link command, it affects the way glibc does some things.

Comment: @Slava Thanks, I'll give it a try. Unfortunately, since the error cannot be easily reproduced, it may take months to be sure that it had any effect...